# Cucumber (Gherkin): How to use parameters of type non string (Long) in test steps?

Tags: gherkin, cucumber-java

I'm trying to write some Cucumber tests in order to get familiarized with the Gherkin language.
Here is a feature sample:

```
  Scenario: Get a customer
    When an user wants to get a customer <id>
    Then an HTTP 200 status together with the requested customer data is returned
```

And here is the associated step:

```
@When("an user wants to get a customer {long}")
public void anUserWantsToGetACustomer(Long id)
{
  ...
}
```

Running the verify goal raises the following exception:

```
[ERROR] Get a customer  Time elapsed: 0.023 s  <<< ERROR!
io.cucumber.junit.UndefinedStepException: 
The step "an user wants to get a customer <long>" is undefined. You can implement it using the snippet(s) below:

@When("an user wants to get a customer <id>")
public void anUserWantsToGetACustomer_id() {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();
}
```

Obviously, it doesn't understand that the step method need to take a parameter of type Long. However, for parameter of type String it works, for example:

```
Scenario: Get a customer
  When an user wants to get a customer "<id>"
  Then an HTTP 200 status together with the requested customer data is returned
  ...
  @When("an user wants to get a customer {string}")
  public void anUserWantsToGetACustomer(String id)
  {
    ...
  }
```

So, what kind of syntax should I use here in order that my tests accepts a Long parameter ?

Kind regards,

Seymour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `{long}` in your step defs

```
Scenario: test long type
     Given I log the type of 41

@Given("I log the type of {long}")
        public void logType(Long testLong ) {
            System.out.println("type of 41 is:"+ testLong.getClass());
       }
```

prints

```
type of 41 is:class java.lang.Long
```

This also works

```
 Scenario Outline: test long type
     Given I log the type of <id> 
  
      Examples:
        |id|
        |  41  |

  @Given("I log the type of {long}")
        public void logType(Long testLong ) {
            System.out.println("type of " +testLong +" is:"+ testLong.getClass());
       }
```

Comment: What's the point of using 41 when I need a Long type ? Imagine a scenario supposed to return an item identified by its ID. It would read something like: "when an user wants to get the item having the ID <id>". Now, compare this scenario with the following: "when an user wants to get the item with the ID 41". Do you see the difference ? Unless you're providing one scenario for each possible value of the ID, such a statement doesn't make sense.

Comment: It was just to show that you can use can `{long}` . The point here is the conversion

Comment: "The point here is the conversion". While it might be your point, it is not mine.

Comment: `"what kind of syntax should I use here in order that my tests accepts a Long parameter"`